# Swift "change an item in an array" Noobie in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, variables

how can i change an item in an array (Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String')

```
var headersSend: HTTPHeaders = [
            "changeMe": "none",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
  
  headersSend[0] = "changeMe" : "Changed!" // <--- ? Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'
```

Comment: That's a dictionary, not an array. I'd tend to say `headersSend["changeMe"] = "Changed"`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headersSend` is a dictionary, not an array. It stores key-value pairs, where key and value are both of type `String`.

Accessing through `headersSend[0]` means you want to change item at key `0`. You have a compilation error because dictionary's key is not of type `Int`. You have to use `String` key instead.

That's the way we change value at specific key

`dictionary[key] = newValue`

In your case it would be

`headersSend["changeMe"] = "Changed!"`

---

I suggest you to read more about collection types [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html).

Comment: //It stores key-value pairs .. thank you +++++ 